# Insert photo loop: How do I skip to `Next` when path is empty?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert pictures in an Excel sheet next to its model name.

There is a loop to insert pictures row by row till last model.

The problem occurs when **ppath** is empty (blank http page). If empty the macro should go to `Next`.

`On error resume next` is crashing Excel. Error handler I tried is not working also (getting debug code on ppath).

How do I skip to `Next` when ppath is empty (no picture)?
Here is my code:

```vb
Sub insert_foto()
Dim i As Long
Dim ppath As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet")
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

With ws
    ws.Range("A6:A" & lastrow).RowHeight = 90
End With

'On Error Resume Next - is crashing excel when ppath is empty
On Error GoTo ErrHandler    
For i = 6 To lastrow

    ' picture name in col A, ppath is where the pictures are
    ppath = "http://aa/bb/" & CStr(Cells(i, 2).Value & "-F1.jpg")
    'If ppath <> "" Then -tried this solution but not working

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=ppath, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
      savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=50, Height:=85)

        .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Left + (ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Width - .Width) / 2
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Top + (ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Height - .Height) / 2
        .Placement = 1

    End With
  '  End If
ErrHandler:
    'Resume Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then`.

Comment: Your path is never empty which is why the check fails, so like BigBen suggests, check if the cell is empty.

Comment: But the cells are my models list in excel and its not the case. I get the model name from  CStr(Cells(i, 2).Value but some models are not uploaded to ppath (website). So i dont know if your soulution is what i mean?

Comment: Oh... in that case this requires a different solution. Sorry, misunderstood what you meant by "when ppath is empty."

Comment: So its when i go to website with model that is causing error i get 404 not found on page.

Comment: You should change the title of your question, it is misleading: Path is not empty, the problem is that the file is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AddPicture` is asked to load an image that doesn't exist, it will throw an runtime error and of course not adding a new shape - that means it returns `Nothing`. To prevent the runtime error, you can insert a `On Error Resume Next`-statement, but please only for the one statement.

You mention that if you use `On Error Resume Next`, Excel crashes. With *crashes*, do you mean that Excel really crashes with an error message or that Excel seems to hang (no longer reacting)? If you try to access an image from the internet that doesn't exist, Excel needs to wait for a timeout and that can take some time (I had to wait for 60s for a server). If you do this multiple times, the execution may easily take a lot of time and during that, Excel will basically freeze. Adding a `DoEvents` will let Excel at least react after every download.

Have a look to the following code. It tries to load an image and save the result into a variable. If the loading fails, the variable will be `Nothing` and you know that the loading failed. As you are already using a worksheet variable, you should use that rather than `ActiveSheet`.

```
Dim sh As Shape
On Error Resume Next
Set sh = Nothing
Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=pPath, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=50, Height:=85)
if sh is Nothing then
    ' Try an alternative image
    Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=pPath2, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
            savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=50, Height:=85)
End If
On Error GoTo 0
DoEvents
If sh Is Nothing Then
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = "Image not found"
Else
    With sh
        .Left = ws.Cells(i, 1).Left + (ws.Cells(i, 1).Width - .Width) / 2
        .Top = ws.Cells(i, 1).Top + (ws.Cells(i, 1).Height - .Height) / 2
        .Placement = 1
    End With
End If
```

Comment: You solved my problem, thank you so much! My excel was just crashing on error resume next statment without any debug or warning it closed all my workbooks

Comment: Dont know if you can help me again, what if i get "Image not found" and i want give second path to picture insted of this text? I tried to do ppath2 but im getting error 1004.
 If sh Is Nothing Then
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=ppath2, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=60, Height:=85)

Comment: Assign the shape you create to the Shape variable (`sh`), so use exactly the same statement as above, just replace `pPath` by `ppath2`. You cannot assign a shape to a cell, you can only move the shape to the position where the cell is - this is done in the lower part of the code.

Comment: I updated the code, when the first picture cannot be loaded it tries the 2nd file.

Comment: Thanks man! To bad i cant give you a second "+" :) Somehow while waiting on your response i got it working by going with sh2 statement.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but the logic the answer gave isn't stopping the runtime error when ppath isn't found.

i had to implement the below. it uses an object from a reference pack in which you have to enable in your macro called Windows Script Host Object Model

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim strFileName As String

strFileName = fso.GetFileName(ppath)

If strFileName Like "*jpg*" Then
' get images
Else
' do nothing
End If
```

Comment: You should use code formatting in your answer